# Is there a mail client or Thunderbird Addon making email look more like a dialog?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am looking more or less for something like Google Wave, but still using the Standard protocols POP/IMAP/SMTP, so that it's still just Email under the hood.

I'd love to see the messages displayed as a thread, messages sent By me should be added to the threas (Not put aside in a folder called "Sent items".) and it would be nice if it could magically hide quoted prior messages and signatures.

As i am currenty using Thunderbird, an Addon would be great, but another Tool would be okay, too. (I am aware that TB offers a threaded view, but it doesn't meet any of the wishes I wrote above.) I'd be Happy to See suggestions, as my research on the Web did Not reveal anything so far.

EDIT: I am looking for a Desktop Client, as I Do Not want to be dependent on third Party Websites or Tools.

Comment: Gmail is a POP3 email client and does the things you ask.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I am looking for a Desktop Client. Being dependent on third Party Websites is nothing I like, and I Do Not want Google to read all my Email. I have updated the question. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Thunderbird Conversations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/) add-on.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be exactly what I am looking for :) Great...